# Autopilot Landscape fails to install

Tags: networking, juju, openstack, lxc, openstack-autopilot

i am hoping someone can answer this, my autopilot keeps failing. After inspecting a log i noticed that LXC containers cannot communicate with external/public network. To make this clearer i can ping internet from the LXC container DNS resolution works but i cannot ping the "public" network i created with a separate VLAN. L3 inter VLAN routing is enabled on the switch. The container has an ip address in 192.168.26.0/23 and public network is set to 192.168.24.0/23

Here is the output:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:16:3e:8d:d3:97
          inet addr:192.168.27.153  Bcast:192.168.27.255  Mask:255.255.254.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::216:3eff:fe8d:d397/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:13972 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1580 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:997390 (997.3 KB)  TX bytes:315638 (315.6 KB)
```

pinging internet:

```
juju-machine-0-lxc-3:~$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=2.03 ms
```

cannot ping "public" network:

```
juju-machine-0-lxc-3:~$ ping 192.168.24.2
PING 192.168.24.2 (192.168.24.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.168.24.2 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

however i can ping vlan interface:

```
juju-machine-0-lxc-3:~$ ping 192.168.24.1
PING 192.168.24.1 (192.168.24.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.24.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.52 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.24.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=1.92 m
```

Comment: I would guess your switch isn't passing your VLAN traffic, doesn't really seem like an Openstack problem.  `traceroute 192.168.24.2` does it route and then fail at `.2`?

Comment: It fails at the GW but the switch is passing VLAN traffic fine i can ing both sides from any host except LXC containers. If i add  route to LXC to just send that traffic via default gw i can ping a across fine. Can you add a route to maas to automatically add to all the LXC containers?